# Laravel: how to delete the row in different table in the same id.....?

Tags: php, laravel

```
PageUsers::where('pageUser_id', Auth::user()->user_id)
->where('page_user_level', 0)
->join('page','page.page_id','=','page_users.page_Id')
->delete();
```

how to delete row in different table with the same id laravel?

Comment: Could you show your migration of `pageUsers` and `page` table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why  don't you get the user id first and delete each rows separately.